# Code that can look at open browser tabs and store the urls?

Tags: url, browser

I am attempting to write a program that looks at the current browser you have open, goes through each tab, and copies and pastes each page's url into a notepad file.

I have no issue with writing the file; my main concern is that I can't find anything in any language that can look at the browser, sift through the tabs, and scrape the url.

Does anyone know if this would be possible, any code that might be able to help (in any language), or if something like this exists? I would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Probably the best thing would be to write an extension for your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software I was looking for did not exist, so I created it. It's a chrome extension called [Raincheck](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/raincheck/bnkkhcahfcgihpjhpkgcflejdgncncam)